# How to automatically "Add native support" to Android project created from existing source?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, adt

I have an Android project set up for building using the command line, i.e. using ant, that also has some JNI code. When I import the project into Eclipse with the Android ADT the JNI code is not built by default but requires me to manually click Android Tools->Add native support to get the JNI code to build.

Is there a way, either in Eclipse + ADT or in my Android project config files, to make the "Add native support" step happen automatically if JNI code is present in a project?

Comment: Look the link below.This might Help http://mobilepearls.com/labs/ndk-builder-in-eclipse/

Comment: This step is not required in Android Studio. However specific to eclipse the link in the answer below works

Comment: Note that _"Add native support"_ menu actually adds JNI code to your project. Most of the times, this empty cpp file is a useless nuisance. It should be possible to automatically add a `.cproject` file to your project, but I never saw a tool or script that did this. After all, do you import Android JNI projects so often that a couple of extra clicks would matter?

Comment: I noticed that on most recent ADT (ver 23.x) it has stopped adding the useless empty file. Reasons: I import perhaps a few times a week. More importantly, other people import projects and those people have likely never used Eclipse or programmed on Android so I'm trying to get the project import process down to the bare minimum. I'll try the Android studio Beta as this is the future anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I guess "Add native support" will appear after you install the "Android Native Development Tools" plugin.

Help => Install New Software...
[image: How to install]
Check the "Android Native Development Tools" checkbox and press Next.

The following link also guides how to use NDK plugin.

http://tolgaeren.com/blog/2013/7/25/setting-up-android-ndk-development-and-debugging-inside-eclipse

Comment: I have the NDK very happily installed already. That isn't the problem. I'm wanting to automate the project importation so I don't have to click "Add native support"